# incompatible types: Node is not a functional interface

Tags: java

Using openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17

I got the following code. (It is a copy of [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/))

Using javasc to compile, I got this error. `ListInter.java:80: error: incompatible types: Node is not a functional interface`

```
// 1 class has all
class ListInter {

    // like global var
    static Node h1;
    static Node h2; 

    // static class in class 
    static class Node { 
        // val
        int val;
        // next 
        Node next; 

        // constructor 
        Node(int v) {
            // we don't call this, use straight 
            val = v;
            // we don't call this, use straight
            next = null; 
        } 
    } 

    Node getThatNode() {
        // static h1, count
        // no need this 
        int c1 = countNodeNum(h1); 
        // static h2, count
        int c2 = countNodeNum(h2);
        // diff 
        int diff; 

        // c1 list longer than c2 
        if (c1 > c2) {
            // get diff
            diff = c1 - c2; 
            return getJoinedNode(diff, h1, h2); 
        } else {
            // c2 longer than c1 
            diff = c2 - c1; 
            return getJoinedNode(diff, h2, h1); 
        } 
    } 

    Node getJoinedNode(int diff, Node h1, Node h2) {
        // consume
        int i;  
        // point
        Node curr1 = h1;
        // point
        Node curr2 = h2;        

        // consume all diff
        for (i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            // to the end of list, in case 
            if (curr1 == null) { 
                return null; 
            } 
            curr1 = curr1.next; 
        }   

        while(curr1 != null && curr2 != null) {
            if (curr1.val == curr2.val) { 
                return curr1; 
            } 
            curr1 = curr1.next; 
            curr2 = curr2.next; 
        }

        return null;    
    }

    int countNodeNum(Node node) {
        // point
        Node curr;
        int num = 0;        

        curr = node;
        while(curr != null) {
            curr = curr->next;
            num++;
        }

        return num;
    }   

    // main
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // itself
        ListInter list = new ListInter();

        list.h1 = new Node(3); 
        list.h1.next = new Node(6); 
        list.h1.next.next = new Node(15); 
        list.h1.next.next.next = new Node(15); 
        list.h1.next.next.next.next = new Node(30); 

        list.h2 = new Node(10); 
        list.h2.next = new Node(15); 
        list.h2.next.next = new Node(30); 

        System.out.println("The node of intersection is " + list.getThatNode()); 


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `curr = curr->next` to `curr = curr.next` (at line 80)